# org-mode in emacs: how to move all headline one level below

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the org like

```
* second level
** third level
*** fourth level
```

And then I find the second level should be ** second level instead of * second level, so I want to push all headline one level below, the result shoudl be

```
* some heading which I will add manully
** second level
*** third level
**** fouth level
```

Comment: My recollection is that some of these functions (in the following link) have built-in provisions for active regions (i.e., the functions can act upon a blocked set / group of entries) -- take a look at functions containing the words **promote** and **demote** . . .:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html

Comment: "When there is an active region (Transient Mark mode), promotion and demotion work on all headlines in the region. To select a region of headlines, it is best to place both point and mark at the beginning of a line, mark at the beginning of the first headline, and point at the line just after the last headline to change. Note that when the cursor is inside a table (see Tables), the Meta-Cursor keys have different functionality."

Answer (score 6):

With cursor on `second level`, press <kbd>M-S-right</kbd> (calls
`org-shiftmetaright`).

In [worf](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf), it's <kbd>cflq</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Create the new heading and use `org-refile` (`C-c C-w`)  to move "First Level" to under the new heading.  All of the children of the first level will be moved and have their levels changed appropriately.